# Extract content of specific div preserving only certain elements

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, domxpath

I need to extract only textual part of the webpage preserving all and only the `<p> <h2>, <h3>, <h4> and <blockquote>s`.

Now, using DOMXPath and `$div = $xpath->query('//div[@class="story-inner"]');` gives lots of unwanted page elements like pictures, ad blocks, other custom markups, etc. inside of text div.

On the other hand using the following code:

```
$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('<p>');
 for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++) {
    echo $items->item($i)->nodeValue . "<p>";
}
```

gives very nice and clean result very close what I wanted, but with `<h2>, <h3>, <h4> and <blockquotes>` missing.

I wonder is there any DOM-way of (1) indicating only desired page elements and extracting clean result or (2) efficient way of cleaning up the output obtained by using `$div = $xpath->query('//div[@class="story-inner"]');`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `OR` inside your xpath query in this case. Just cascade those tags with it get those only desired ones.

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/russian/international/2015/02/150218_ukraine_debaltseve_fighting";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$html = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$tags = array('p', 'h2');
$children_needed = implode(' or ', array_map(function($tag){ return sprintf('name()="%s"', $tag); }, $tags));
$query = "//div[@class='story-body__inner']//*[$children_needed]";
$div_children = $xpath->query($query);
if($div_children->length > 0) {
    foreach($div_children as $child) {
        echo $doc->saveHTML($child);
    }
}
```

Comment: This returns only the first `<p>` and I need all of them, of course.

Comment: @Sasha oh okay, that wasn't said, but just use `//*` to get them all

Comment: unfortunately, that also didn't work. I've just pasted the whole code in the post above. Could you please take a look what is wrong with my code?

Comment: @Sasha you should have posted that earlier :) anyways, i made some revisions. check out the demo

Comment: Demo works fine, but as soon as I copy it locally, it gives: `Warning: DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in /home/test/domains/sub.test.com/public_html/test.php on line 20 Warning: DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects exactly 0 parameters, `

Comment: @Sasha what PHP version ar you using anyway? the changelog function says added since `5.3.6` http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php just change it to `echo $child->nodeValue`

Comment: PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Oct 30 2014 20:12:53) and unfortunately I can't upgrade. However, `echo $child->nodeValue` worked fine to return only texts and I really need to preserve all p and h2, h3 elements.

Comment: just add tags inside `$tags` if necessary, thats what i though, sorry @Sasha i don't work as freelance as i already have a full plate on the office work, this is just me answering some questions here that i know a little bit in my spare time. if i stumble in one of your questions in the future, it try to answer it i can. im glad this helped

Comment: @Sasha why the heck is the move to discussion not working, bugged, anyways, what you do mean by preserving all `p` and other stuff anyways? does this mean the tag? like this? `echo "<$child->tagName>$child->nodeValue</$child->tagName>";`

Comment: Sorry @Ghost, I just wanted to get it done properly. Accepted your reply again. Apparently, I have to move to another server with PHP 5.3.6 as `echo $child->nodeValue` stripping out all p and h2 tags.

Comment: @Sasha yes that would be the best thing to do, why not bump the upgrade to 5.5, take advantage to some of the new functions. sure glad this helped

Comment: I finally moved my project to another server with PHP 5.5.9 and your code works great. Except one last thing - the output contains <a> link tags and I really wanted to indicate desired tags in $tags array, where I currently have `$tags = array('p', 'h2');` No 'a' as you see, however it still gives the output with 'a's. Can you improve the code, so that it doesn't contain any links?

Comment: @Sasha g*d d*mmit the chat isn't working anyway im kinda busy right know  on an office project here's a quick dirty fix http://pastebin.com/TSwdxY9c

Comment: with little bit of modification as on http://pastebin.com/uHV25F3C it works correctly. Otherwise it was concatenating the text of the link. Thanks!

Comment: also could you please remove reference to BBC in your reply because of their proprietary policy. I used that link as just an example. Thanks!

Comment: @Sasha yeah glad yhis helped

Comment: do you know btw how to save all the extracted text into a single variable? Using `$paragraph = (string)$doc->saveHTML($child); $body = $body.$paragraph;` within the iteration and then printing value of $body after the iteration for some reason duplicates the text of stripped of <a> tags :(

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly.. is this what you are asking for...

```
$output1=preg_match('/^.*<tagName>(.*)<\/tagName>/', $value,$match1);
```

Match with the tagnames and get the data in between them by using `preg_match`...

Comment: I need to use PHP DOM as using preg_match or regex is not applicable in my case.